# DECS activity will not start

Tags: oracle, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

My Domino Enterprise Connection Services (DECS) activity will not start. In the display, an hourglass icon indicates that the activity is starting, but it never resumes to the "active" state with the antenna icon.

I am using Domino Server 9.0.1 x64 on a Windows Server 2008.
My DECS activity is using a connection to Oracle Inventory EBS server in UNIX with an Oracle 12c client installed on my windows server machine. The Oracle server is accessible from the windows server machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem, I realized my "DECS Administrator" lotus application was duplicated. Two instances were running at the same time. Removing the duplicated application solved the problem and my DECS activity would start normally.